# Drupal 7 saving content each time i upload an image

Tags: image, duplicates, drupal-7

Each time i upload an image to a custom content type node it is saved creating a new node. If i upload 3 images, 4 content nodes are generated with the same name. One for each image and the intended node when clicking save after filling all fields.